# Docker : image build failed

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose

when building docker apache image, the building fail in this step :

```
Step n/m : COPY httpd-foreground /usr/local/bin/
```

> ERROR: Service 'apache' failed to build: COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder511740141/httpd-foreground: no such
>   file or directory

this is my docker_compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_octopus_dev
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  apache:
    build: .
    container_name: apache_octopus_dev
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

this is my docker file

```
FROM debian:jessie-backports

# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
#RUN groupadd -r www-data && useradd -r --create-home -g www-data www-data
...

COPY httpd-foreground /usr/local/bin/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["httpd-foreground"]
```

any help please?

Comment: Do you have a file called `httpd-foreground` in your build context (the directory at the end of the `docker build` command). Have you excluded it with a `.dockerignore`?

Comment: no i dont have .dockerignore file i placed the file in wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths in a Dockerfile are always relative to the the context directory. The context directory is the positional argument passed to docker build (often .).

I should place the httpd-foreground file in the same folder of dockerfile.

From : https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/90